# Find a powerset of a set in C

Tags: c, recursion, set

The code below is an implementation of purely recursive solution to find a powerset of any given set. The input set is  a string, and the output - array of strings. Both of them are wrapped into a structure for convenience. The underlying algorithm is pretty common one. The recursive function executes exactly 2^n - 1 times.

I've intentionally removed all memory allocation error checking to make the snippet shorter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
   
typedef struct set {
    char* data;
    int size;
} Set;

typedef struct pset {
    char **data;
    int size;
} PSet;

Set *initSet(char *str) {
    Set *set;
    set = malloc(sizeof(Set));  

    set->data = calloc(strlen(str) + 1, 1);      
    strcpy(set->data, str);
    set->size = strlen(str);

    return set;
}

PSet *initPSet(const Set* sset) {
    // wrapper for recursive function getPSet
    void getPSet(PSet *pset, const Set *inputStr, int buffer, int index);

    PSet *pset = malloc(sizeof(PSet));
 
    pset->data = malloc (sizeof(char *) * (1 << sset->size));
  
    // empty set is a subset of any set
    pset->data[pset->size] = calloc(2, 1);

    strcpy(pset->data[pset->size], "");
    pset->size = 1;

    // in case the input set is empty return a set with just one element
    if (sset->size != 0)
        getPSet(pset, sset, 0, 0);

    return pset;
}

void getPSet(PSet *pset, const Set *set, int buffer, int index) {
    //allocating place for a new subset
    pset->data[pset->size] = calloc(strlen(pset->data[buffer]) + 2, sizeof(char));

    strcpy(pset->data[pset->size], pset->data[buffer]);
    pset->data[pset->size][strlen(pset->data[buffer])] = set->data[index];
    pset->size++;

    // local variable pos keeps track of a position of a prefix stored in pset for future recurrent calls
    int pos = pset->size - 1;

    index++;
   
    if (index >= set->size) return;

    getPSet(pset, set, buffer, index);
    getPSet(pset, set, pos, index);
}

int main () {

    Set *sset = initSet("abcd");
    PSet *pset;

    pset = initPSet(sset);

    for (int i = 0; i < pset->size; ++i) {
        printf("{%s}\n", pset->data[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `pset->size` is used in `initPSet` without having been initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a review of a small portion of code:

```
PSet *pset = malloc(sizeof(PSet));
pset->data = malloc (sizeof(char *) * (1 << sset->size));
pset->data[pset->size] = calloc(2, 1);
```

`pset->size` is not yet assigned a value. `pset->data[pset->size]` is a **Bug**.  [@1201ProgramAlarm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/254532/find-a-powerset-of-a-set-in-c/254543#comment501982_254532)

`sizeof(char *)` --> Is that the correct size?  I need to look for the declarations of `pset` up some lines and then the definition of `PSet` some 20 lines upstream.

Consider below instead - no need to check if the correct type.  The size is correct by inspection of this line alone.

```
pset->data = malloc(sizeof pset->data[0] * (1 << sset->size));
```

Later code uses `int` for indexing and buffer size, yet could have used `unsigned` and incur no additional cost in performance.  To support `unsigned`, add `u`:

```
pset->data = malloc(sizeof pset->data[0] * (1u << sset->size));
```

---

**Redundant string length calculation**

Compiler may not optimize the 2 `strlen()` calls into 1.  Recommend to do so by direct code.

```
//pset->data[pset->size] = calloc(strlen(pset->data[buffer]) + 2, sizeof(char));
//strcpy(pset->data[pset->size], pset->data[buffer]);
//pset->data[pset->size][strlen(pset->data[buffer])] = set->data[index];

size_t len = strlen(pset->data[buffer];
pset->data[pset->size] = calloc(len + 2, sizeof(char));
strcpy(pset->data[pset->size], pset->data[buffer]);  // or memcpy()
pset->data[pset->size][len] = set->data[index];  // re-use `len`
```

---

**Use `const` for unchanged refenced data**

It better conveys code's intent, allows for some optimizations and greater functionally usage.

```
// Set *initSet(char *str) {
Set *initSet(const char *str) {
```

---

**Missing freeing of memory**

For general usage of these routines, de-allocation routines are needed like `uninitSet()` and `uninitPSet()`.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback. I especially like the idiom of dereferencing a pointer variable for the calculation of memory being allocated. The only thing that isn't that clear to me is using `unsigned` instead of `int`. Do you use it for better demonstration of your intentions or it yields some advantages in efficiency/allows for certain optimizations?

Comment: @anfauglit Increased range with `u`.  `1u << sset->size` good for `sset->size` in the range [0...N).  `1 << sset->size` good for `sset->size` in the range [0...N-1).  Same efficiency.  Other code would need to move from `int` indexing to support this wider range.